# How to Search Table1 Column Value is present in Table2 Column or not in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Hi I have two tables with same column .
First I need to take 1 column value from table 1 then I need to search for value weather is exists in same column of table 2.
 can anybody know how to do this in spotfire?

Comment: How to do this in spotfire?

Comment: One suggestion in providing good questions is to include any code or processes you have tried unsuccessfully to show where you are at and help provide context and clarity of what you're trying to do. Screenshots can be helpful as well when code does not tell the whole story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to attempt a join and then perform some logic on the join results. Below is how I would do this:

1. Create a Calculated Column in Table2 named EXISTS with the expression of `TRUE`.
2. Go to Insert>Columns and choose to add columns to Table1 from Table2.
3. Match on your primary key (in my case the column "LETTER")
4. Select EXISTS from the checkboxes to add and use the Join method of `Left single match` in order to preserve your number of records and hit Finish.
5. Now you have a column named EXISTS in your Table1 that is either null or TRUE. If you would like to have it be TRUE or FALSE you can create a calculated column based upon it that evaluates if it's NULL or not like so: `[EXISTS] Is Not Null`. I named mine "EXISTS_TF" in the example below.

My data and resulting columns after the above:

[image: spotfire_example_1]

You should now be able to filter and do calculations based on your new column(s).