# spotfire: search a column of another table

Tags: search, calculated-columns, spotfire

I'm trying to make a calculated column in Spotfire, where a specific value has to be present in a column of another table before a new value is assigned.

My expression looks like this:

```
If(Find('Specific value first table',**'present in second table'**) is Null, 0, 'New Value')
```

I have no idea how to involve this second table in my search, does anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to reference another table when creating a calculated column. However, I think we can solve your problem all the same.

What you'll want to do is attempt to insert columns from your other table by joining on the column that holds the values you're searching for and then check if it exists with a simple calculated column. In your case you'll want to set the null values as your new value and keep the existing values. Something like `case when [new_column] is null then 'new_value' else [new_column] end`.

Below is a previous similar but slightly different question I answered with my answer copied below for convenience.

[How to Search Table1 Column Value is present in Table2 Column or not in spotfire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842975/how-to-search-table1-column-value-is-present-in-table2-column-or-not-in-spotfire/29930605#29930605)

1. Create a Calculated Column in Table2 named EXISTS with the expression of `TRUE`.
2. Go to Insert>Columns and choose to add columns to Table1 from Table2.
3. Match on your primary key (in my case the column "LETTER")
4. Select EXISTS from the checkboxes to add and use the Join method of `Left single match` in order to preserve your number of records and hit Finish.
5. Now you have a column named EXISTS in your Table1 that is either null or TRUE. If you would like to have it be TRUE or FALSE you can create a calculated column based upon it that evaluates if it's NULL or not like so: `[EXISTS] Is Not Null`. I named mine "EXISTS_TF" in the example below.

My data and resulting columns after the above:

[image: spotfire_example_1]

You should now be able to filter and do calculations based on your new column(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It took me some time to make it work, because my primairy key is also a calculated column. Therefore I needed to freeze the column first. But now it works perfectly. Great!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you could find help here. One goal Stack Exchange sites is to keep questions and answers clean and uncluttered. To show thanks if you find it deserved you can upvote answers given and useful comments on your question as well. Accepting an answer by clicking the check mark is an option to show which answer you feel is the best solution. You can change your choice or simply uncheck the answer at any time. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Pia, just to point out that Calculated Columns created through transformations (either when first adding the data table, or from the menu Insert>>Transformation) are treated as "imported" column types instead of "calculated". this means that, although you're unable to modify the expression, you will be able to use the column as a primary key column for other transformations.



of course, you can always File>>Replace Data Table and use the original source, then re-apply any transformations if you need to change the expression.