# Spotfire lookup a value from a calculated column

Tags: spotfire

I have a data set in spotfire where I'm creating a calculated column that returns an entity name (the entity name being returned is also in column A).  Once the entity name is returned from the calculated column, I need a data attribute that is in a different column but is on the row of the entity name.

I've attached a snapshot of data.  The calculated field returns 'Company C'.  I need to create a column that looks up company C in column A and returns the location of company C.

In excel I would use a VLOOKUP to lookup company C on columns A:C and return column 3.  But I can't figure out how to do this in Spotfire.  Any help?

[image]

Comment: I like this... I’ll try and get you something tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

@Carson- My answer is slightly similar to that of @blakeoft.

Here is my observation. It is difficult to lookup values from columns in the same table in Spotfire. Data tables in Spotfire act more like database tables. However, we can achieve the desired result by adding a little step.

**Here are the steps:**

**Step 1:** Create a table by pivoting your existing table with two fields `Company` and `Location`. Let's name this as **Lookup table**.

**Lookup table screenshot:**

[image]

**Step 2:** Now, add Location column to your existing table from Lookup table by joining the two tables with ***Calculated field in your existing table*** and ***Company in your Lookup table*** as shown below. Select `Location` field which you would like to add to your existing table.
*Note: Ensure the join method selected is 'Left outer' which is a default selection.*

However, you should be careful while using a calculated field as a primary key to connect two tables. Please check this SO post.

[spotfire: search a column of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343670/spotfire-search-a-column-of-another-table)

[image]

**Final Table with Location added:**

[image]

Comment: I like the solution of using a pivot table.  The source data is coming from an SQL statement - do you think it's better to add this logic in SQL and then import it into spotfire?  Or is it better to add this logic in spotfire?

Comment: @Carson- I would suggest you to complete all the data transformation steps in database itself (if possible) before pulling in data into Spotfire. I am little skeptical about using calculated column as a primary key for connecting tables in Spotfire.

Comment: yep! always try to do any data massaging outside of Spotfire. Spotfire can definitely handle it, but as the gentlement above point out, you'll get better performance in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can add columns with one of the join criteria being a calculated column, unless you calculate the column when you're reading in the dataset. So let's assume that you **did** in fact add this calculated column when you read in the data.

You would click `Insert` > `Columns...` Then choose your table in the `Add columns to data table` drop down box, as well as choosing the same table in the `Add columns from` menu. Click `Next`. On the left side, click `CalculatedField` to select it, then click `Company` on the right to select it. Press `Match Selected` and hit `Next`. Select `Location` and click `Finish`. This will embed your table into your analysis (I don't like doing this). You could also add a copy of your table to your analysis and choose it in the `Add columns from` menu to avoid the embedding. You'll also probably want to rename the new column as it will be called `Location (2)`.

I'm on Spotfire 6.5, so the button names might vary.