# Spotfire Limit Visualization using Iron Python Scripting

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a data table which has a column ID mapped with another column PID.
I have another datatable which contains detail data for respective ID's.I want to add a column PID to my second table according to its respective ID's using the first table.
My main purpose is to implement a dropdown using the PID column and limit the data in the datatable visualization of the second table.

Answer (score 2):

@Saumya- This can be implemented without using iron python script.

- Assuming you have added PID column to your second table. This can be
  done by matching the ID columns from both the tables. Refer to this
  SO post for adding columns from another table. A part of the answer
  talks about this.

[Spotfire lookup a value from a calculated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100070/spotfire-lookup-a-value-from-a-calculated-column)

- Now, create a drop down property control which is linked to your PID
  column so that it has unique values from that column.
- After you have created this drop down in text area, go to data table
  properties. In `Data > Limit data using expression` section add the
  below expression.

> "${propertyname}"=[PID]

Based on the drop-down selection, your table gets filtered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I second ksp's answer! Limit data using expression is the most straightforward way to do this. it /is/ possible in IronPython (I've answered that question somewhere on this tag; do a quick search or check my history) however I wouldn't go that route unless you had some functional need to do so.