# Spotfire: insert calculated column based on data from another table

Tags: spotfire

I have 2 tables, I want to add a calculated column in Table 1, to show how many License IDs in Table 2.(the yellow column is what I want to add in Spotfire)

for example REF ID=A001, A0002 have one license id in Table 2, A0007 has 2(18845682,ABCDEFG), A0008 has zero

if I do not join these 2 tables, how to meet my needs?
attached two tables, please see the attachment[image]

New requirement, also add the license id to table 1, only display license id when column e =1
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1994358- An easy way to accomplish this is, add pivot transformation to `Table2` which counts `LICENSE ID`. Now, add this column `LICENSE ID_COUNT` to `Table1` by matching `REF ID` in both the tables.

Similar question posted on SO few days back, please check the below link.

[Spotfire lookup a value from a calculated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100070/spotfire-lookup-a-value-from-a-calculated-column/48107127#48107127)

**Below are the screenshots:**

[image]

---

**Modified Answer:**

As per your latest requirement, here is the modified answer.

- Using this solution, `Table2` need not be pivoted. Instead, add a calculated column `get_license` to `Table2` with the expression below. This expression shows license ID's with license count = 1.

> If(Count([License ID]) over ([REF ID])=1,[License ID],null)

*Note: You can show `LIC_count` as a separate column with expression `Count([License ID]) over ([REF ID])`.*

- Now, add this calculated column to `Table1` by matching `REF_ID`.

**Final output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you ksp585, this is a very helpful solution. I have one more question, in table 1, we've already got licsens id_count field,  if I want to add one more column contain a condition below:
if Lic_ID count is 1 add the license id to this column, if Lic_ID count >1 or NULL add "no lic matched" string in this column
how to meet this need?

Comment: @user1994358- I would suggest you to keep the column `License ID_count`in the background in `Table 1` and add a calculated column which prints values based on the condition 
    If([License ID_count]=1,[License ID_count],null). Note, you cannot add string values to an integer column. If this answered your question, please go ahead and accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark.

Comment: i mean add the Lincese ID column to table1, please see new screenshot in my question

Comment: @user1994358- Posted modified answer. Going forward, please post separate questions which are different from the original ones to avoid confusion.